# Does <!DOCTYPE html> make the encoding definition obsolete?

Tags: html, unicode, doctype

[It means](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_utf8.asp), UTF-8 is the standard HTML5 encoding. If the `html` DOCTYPE is defined as `<!DOCTYPE html>` do i need to define the encoding of the page, like with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

**PS**: i should add the cause, why i'm asking. My pages are saved as UTF-8, doctype is defined as `<!DOCTYPE html>`. But i even got a message from a Mac user, he would have broken german diacritical characters. I know this issue since long, pre-unicode time - and thought, UTF-8 is the definitive solution for it.

**PPS**: there are two kinds of broken font face. I add two screenshots i got from users.

[image: Broken font face 1]

[image: Broken font face 2]

Comment: It's needless only if the default of UTF-8 is in use, but if someone else uses some other character set then the `meta` tag is one of the possible ways of defining this

Comment: i think i should add the cause for asking this question. Did it.

Comment: You say "my pages are saved as UTF-8", but do you mean with or without BOM? If there is no meta command, a BOM makes the guess for the browser a lot easier.

Comment: @MrLister without, always without.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[DOCTYPE html](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#the-doctype):**

*DOCTYPEs are required for legacy reasons.*

In HTML, the doctype is the required `"<!DOCTYPE html>"` preamble found at the top of all documents.

Its purpose is to prevent a browser from switching into so-called [“quirks mode”](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode) when rendering a document.

That is, the `"<!DOCTYPE html>"` doctype ensures that **the browser makes a best-effort attempt at following the relevant specifications**, rather than using a different rendering mode that is incompatible with some specifications.

---

**meta charset**:

If the `charset` attribute is set, the `meta` element is a charset declaration, giving the character encoding in which the document is encoded.

You are right, the default character encoding in HTML-5 is UTF-8, but if an HTML5 web page uses a different character set than UTF-8, it should be specified in the  tag like:

```
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
```

So if your page uses UTF-8 you can omit it, even though a good practice I believe would be to keep it anyway. But if you use a different encoding, you need it.

> The rule, in general, would be: Specify your character encoding

To help browsers render the text on your page, you should always specify an encoding for your document. This encoding should appear at the top of the document (or frame) as some browsers won't recognize charset declarations that appear deep in the document.

In addition, you should make sure that your web server is not sending conflicting HTTP headers. A header such as `content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1` will override any charset declarations in your page.

Comment: i've added the cause of asking this question. You answer is very profund - would you add something to it knowing the cause of asking?

Comment: My guess is - you should not rely on default stuff in your case. Try to use `<meta charset="some-encoding">` to specify explicitly the encoding used by your page.

Comment: @Evgeniy Also, please take a look at a small part I added to my answer called: Specify your character encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening this page: http://alohci.net/static/encoding.html

It contains `<!DOCTYPE html>` but no other information about the encoding. What do you see?

Do you see this:

[image: Characters is handled as UTF-8]

or this

[image: Characters is handled as WIN-1252]

Or something else?

If you see the second image, as I do, then the page is being handled as WIN-1252, not UTF-8. But depending where in the world you are, you may see something different.

Comment: Thank you for interesting! I added screenshots of broken font face.